# Merging two dataframes by stringmatch with dplyr and stringdist

Tags: r, dplyr, stringdist

I'm attempting to do a dplyr left join on two dataframes based on greatly similar language (that's not exact).

DF1:

```
title | records
Bob's show, part 1 | 42
Time for dinner | 77
Horsecrap | 121
```

DF2:

```
showname | counts
Bob's show part 1 | 772
Dinner time | 89
No way Jose | 123
```

I execute this to get the string distances as a vector using the stringdist package/library:

```
titlematch <- amatch(df1$title,df2$showname)
```

The vector looks like... well, an integer vector:

```
titlematch
1
2
NA
```

Normally if I had exact matches I'd do:

```
blended <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("title" = "showname"))
```

How do I do the left join using the vector as the record selector so that the end outcome would be:

```
title | records | showname | counts
Bob's show, part 1 | 42 | Bob's show part 1 | 772
Time for dinner | 77 | Dinner time | 89
```

With the third non-match excluded because there's not a probable match in the vector (NA).

Comment: you could make the cartesian product with `tidyr::crossing()` and then filter that - expensive if the data sets are large

Comment: Have you looked at [`fuzzyjoin`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[camille suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959725/merging-two-dataframes-by-stringmatch-with-dplyr-and-stringdist/55961589#comment98571598_55959725):

> Have you looked at [`fuzzyjoin`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html)?

I had never heard of `fuzzyjoin` before, but I tried it and loved it. `stringdist_left_join` was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shot,

```
library(stringdist)
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(temp = amatch(title, df2$showname, maxDist = 10)) %>%
  bind_cols(df2[.$temp, ]) %>%
  select(-temp)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  title              records showname          counts
  <chr>                <int> <chr>              <int>
1 Bob's show, part 1      42 Bob's show part 1    772
2 Time for dinner         77 Dinner time           89
3 Horsecrap              121 Dinner time           89
```

I'm unable to reproduce your numeric matching vector, `amatch(df1$title, df2$showname)` gives me `[1] NA NA NA` as it looks like the default is 0.1, so I set `maxDist` to 10.

At the end, you could always add `%>% filter(is.na(showname))` to remove any row which had no match.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(title = c("Bob's show, part 1", "Time for dinner", 
"Horsecrap"), records = c(42L, 77L, 121L)), .Names = c("title", 
"records"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(showname = c("Bob's show part 1", "Dinner time", 
"No way Jose"), counts = c(772L, 89L, 123L)), .Names = c("showname", 
"counts"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```